# FAKE Fsc task is writing build products to wrong directory

Tags: f#, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

I'm just learning F#, and setting up a FAKE build harness for a hello-world-like application.  (Though the phrase "Hell world" does occasionally come to mind... :-) I'm using a Mac and emacs (generally trying to avoid GUI IDEs by preference).

After a bit of fiddling about with documentation, here's how I'm invoking the F# compiler via FAKE:

```
let buildDir  = @"./build-app/"                        // Where application build products go

Target "CompileApp" (fun _ ->                          // Compile application source code
  !! @"src/app/**/*.fs"                                // Look for F# source files
  |> Seq.toList                                        // Convert FileIncludes to string list
  |> Fsc (fun p ->                                     //  which is what the Fsc task wants
    {p with                                            //
       FscTarget = Exe                                 //
       Platform  = AnyCpu                              //
       Output    = (buildDir + "hello-fsharp.exe") })  // *** Writing to . instead of buildDir?
)                                                      //
```

That uses `!!` to make a `FileIncludes` of all the sources in the usual way, then uses `Seq.toList` to change that to a `string list` of filenames, which is then handed off to the `Fsc` task.  Simple enough, and it even seems to work:

```
...
Starting Target: CompileApp (==> SetVersions)
FSC with args:[|"-o"; "./build-app/hello-fsharp.exe"; "--target:exe"; "--platform:anycpu";
  "/Users/sgr/Documents/laboratory/hello-fsharp/src/app/hello-fsharp.fs"|]
Finished Target: CompileApp
...
```

However, despite what the console output above says, the actual build products go to the top-level directory, not the build directory.  The message above looks like the `-o` argument is being passed to the compiler with an appropriate filename, but the executable gets put in `.` instead of `./build-app/`.

So, 2 questions:

1. Is this a reasonable way to be invoking the F# compiler in a FAKE build harness?
2. What am I misunderstanding that is causing the build products to go to the wrong place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, or a very similar problem, was reported in [FAKE issue #521](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/521) and seems to have been fixed in [FAKE pull request #601](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/pull/601), which see.

### Explanation of the Problem

As is apparently well-known to everyone but me, the F# compiler as implemented in `FSharp.Compiler.Service` has a practice of skipping its first argument.  See  `FSharp.Compiler.Service/tests/service/FscTests.fs` around line 127, where we see the following nicely informative comment:

```
 // fsc parser skips the first argument by default;
 // perhaps this shouldn't happen in library code.
```

Whether it should or should not happen, it's what *does* happen.  Since the `-o` came first in the arguments generated by `FscHelper`, it was dutifully ignored (along with its argument, apparently).  Thus the assembly went to the default place, not the place specified.

### Solutions

The temporary workaround was to specify `--out:destinationFile` in the `OtherParams` field of the `FscParams` setter *in addition to* the `Output` field; the latter is the sacrificial lamb to be ignored while the former gets the job done.

The longer term solution is to fix the arguments generated by `FscHelper` to have an extra throwaway argument at the front; then these 2 problems will annihilate in a puff of greasy black smoke.  (It's kind of balletic in its beauty, when you think about it.)  This is exactly what was just merged into the master by @forki23:

```
 // Always prepend "fsc.exe" since fsc compiler skips the first argument
 let optsArr = Array.append [|"fsc.exe"|] optsArr
```

So that solution should be in the newest version of FAKE (3.11.0).

The answers to my 2 questions are thus:

1. Yes, this appears to be a reasonable way to invoke the F# compiler.
2. I didn't misunderstand anything; it was just a bug and a fix is in the pipeline.

**More to the point:** the *actual* misunderstanding was that I should have checked the FAKE issues and pull requests to see if anybody else had reported this sort of thing, and that's what I'll do next time.